# Create a DACPAC excluding Views

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, database-backups

I need to backup a database, however it includes in development views (eg. `dev.V_report`). These views result in the following errors being reported when I attempt to create a DACPAC file via `SSMS` > `Extract Data-tier Application`:

```
Validation of the schema model for data package failed.
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dev].[V_MasterFinanceReconciliationSummary]: View: [dev].[V_MasterFinanceReconciliationSummary] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[V_MasterFinanceFull].
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dev].[V_MasterFinanceReconciliationSummary]: View: [dev].[V_MasterFinanceReconciliationSummary] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[V_MasterFinanceFull].[PasTransactionType].
… (etc)
```

Every view with an issue is limited to the `dev` schema, they can't be guaranteed to not have these issues, and I'm unable to move these to a different database. I just need to backup the table schemas, and while I can deselect *tables* in `Extract Data-tier Application` I can't do the same for the problematic views, or the `dev` schema as a whole.

I've tried creating a BACPAC as that would still function as a backup, but I encounter the same issue. I've tried backing up the database using `SqlPackage.exe` in the command line using the following (using Azure AD Login, which is required here):

```
sqlpackage.exe /TargetFile:"C:\temp\DACPAC\output_target.dacpac" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:<server> /SourceDatabaseName:<database> /ua /p:VerifyExtraction=False
```

But this just gives me the following error which I can't find relevant information on:

`*** An unexpected failure occurred: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..`

Any advice on backing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can exclude specific objects or schemas with a [deployment contributor](https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer). This requires some additional code to be compiled and available.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to create a copy of the database. Remove all views on the newly created database using a script. Then export the database the newly created database with all views removed as a bacpac.